# Points not lining up

Tags: java, android, graphics, graph

I'm trying to create a basic graph for my application, but I'm having a small issue with it. Presently, what happens is that my graph is generated as I'd hope, but when I go to graph my points inside of it, the points are always "off by 1", specifically, my point that should sit at spot 15 on the graph is displayed at 14. The same is true for all other points in my graph, as they are also displayed 1 lower than they should be. I tried to add 1 to cond, but that didn't seem to change any of the actual points as they're displayed, and simply shifted my labels on the y axis to start higher. Below is the code that I think is responsible, but if more is needed, simply ask and I shall post what's asked.

Note: This is for a class assignment where the purpose is to generate 2d graphics, so I can't use a graphing class specifically, although I know it be a far easier job to do so.

The code is below:

```
public class GraphicsView extends View {

     ArrayList<Point> points = new ArrayList<Point>();
     Path xPath = new Path();
     Path yPath = new Path();
     Path zPath = new Path();
     Path drawGrid = new Path();
         ...
     Integer xAxis;
     Integer yAxis;


     @Override
     protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
       Integer counter = points.size();
       Integer xCord;
       super.onDraw(canvas);        
       yAxis = this.getHeight();
       xAxis = this.getWidth();
       canvas.drawColor(R.color.Background);
       <Setting different paint objects to the right colors here>
       xPath.moveTo(20, yAxis-20);
       yPath.moveTo(20, yAxis-20);
       zPath.moveTo(20, yAxis-20);
       drawGrid.moveTo(22, yAxis-20);
       drawGrid.lineTo(22, 0);
       canvas.drawPath(drawGrid,grid);
       drawGrid.moveTo(22, yAxis-20);
       drawGrid.lineTo(xAxis, yAxis-22);
       canvas.drawPath(drawGrid,grid);
       //Left right Axis (X)
       for (Integer ctr = counter; ctr > 0; ctr--) {
           Integer value = counter- ctr + 1;
           canvas.drawText(value.toString(), (xAxis-20)/ctr,yAxis-5, grid);
       }
       //Up down Axis (Y)
       for (Integer ctr = 1; ctr < 22; ctr++) {
           Integer value = ctr - 1;
           canvas.drawText(value.toString(), 5, scale(yAxis, ctr), grid);
       }
       for (Point point : points)
       {        
           xCord = ((xAxis -20) / counter);
           xPath.lineTo(xCord, scale(yAxis,point.getxCord()));
           xPath.addCircle(xCord, scale(yAxis, point.getxCord()), 2, Direction.CW);
           yPath.lineTo(xCord, scale(yAxis, point.getyCord()));
           yPath.addCircle(xCord, scale(yAxis,point.getyCord()), 2, Direction.CW);
           zPath.lineTo(xCord, scale(yAxis, point.getzCord()));
           zPath.addCircle(xCord, scale(yAxis, point.getzCord()), 2, Direction.CW);
           canvas.drawPath(xPath, xPaint);
           canvas.drawPath(yPath, yPaint);
           canvas.drawPath(zPath, zPaint);
           counter -= 1;
        }       
     }

     private Integer scale(Integer Axis, Integer cord) {
         Integer point = 0;
         point = (Axis - (((Axis-20)/21)) * cord);
         return point;
     }
}
```

To reiterate, what I'm looking for is a way to resolve it so that when a value is set to 15, it shows it as being along the 15 on the y axis. At present, it shows it as being beside 14.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you call `point.getyCord()` just add a `+ 1` to it.

```
point.getyCord() + 1
```

And can you confirm that when you are setting a y value it is actually going in as the desired value.

Comment: Yeah, when the code was running through it was going through as the required value, it just wasn't displaying itself at the right point. Managed to work it out thanks to you both, so thanks for that.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem lies here:

```
for (Integer ctr = 1; ctr < 22; ctr++) {
    Integer value = ctr - 1;
    canvas.drawText(value.toString(), 5, scale(yAxis, ctr), grid);
```

Your Y axis starts with label `0`, but it puts it at the `1` position, since `value = ctr - 1`. When you use the `scale()` function later on, you don't offset it by one.

Two methods to fix this:

**Modify scale() to offset for you**

```
private Integer scale(Integer Axis, Integer cord) {
    Integer point = 0;
    point = (Axis - (((Axis-20)/21)) * (cord + 1));
    return point;
}
```

If you use this method, you should also get rid of the `value` variable you used when drawing the axis, since you can just use `ctr` for the string as well.

- **Offset your y coordinate every time**

As Colin Gillespie said, you can just add 1 to `point.getCord()`.

---

I prefer the first method, since it's cleaner, and you only ever have to offset it once, in that function. With the second method, any time you ever pass a coordinate to scale, you'll have to remember to offset it.

Comment: That's exactly what I thought the problem was, but I wasn't sure at all. Much appreciated man.

Comment: I should probably add, the reason the first counter is as it is, is due to the multiplication in scale; I didn't want everything starting along the very bottom, so I simply threw that in since it seemed to alleviate that problem with it. Thanks though man.